# HttpWebResponse is wrong for the ContentLength

Tags: c#, http, download, content-length

I have a download method for HTTP protocol. But it seems it doesnt work correctly, something is wrong. I tested it with some url sources and it was correct except the last one. The `ContentLength` property is wrong for the url. It is shown as 210 kb in runtime, but it is 8 MB in fact. I will show it by sharing my code. How to fix it?

Code:

```
    void TestMethod(string fileUrl)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        long contentSize = resp.ContentLength;

        MessageBox.Show(contentSize.ToString());
    }
    private void TestButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url1 = "http://www.calprog.com/Sounds/NealMorseDowney_audiosample.mp3";
        string url2 = "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Canon.mp3";

        TestMethod(url1); //This file size must be 8 MB, but it shows up as 210 kb. This is the problem

        TestMethod(url2); //This file size is correct here, about 2.1 MB 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not allowed to access this url this way (with HttpWebRequest).

if you try to get the response text :

```
    HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    using (var streamreader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var r = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
        long contentSize = r.Length;
        Console.WriteLine(contentSize.ToString());
    }
```

You ll get this response :

```
<html><head><title>Request Rejected</title></head><body>The requested URL was rejected. If you think this is an error, please contact the webmaster. <br><br>Your support ID is: 2719994757208255263</body></html>
```

You must set the UserAgent to be able to get the full response. Like this :

```
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
```

By setting this value the server will think your program is a Firefox browser.

So these few lines of code should do the trick :

```
   void TestMethod(string fileUrl)
   {
       HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(fileUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
       req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0";
       HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
       long contentSize = resp.ContentLength;
       Console.WriteLine(contentSize.ToString());
    }
```

Have a good day !

Comment: It works fine. I didn't like using `StreamReader` because it waits the file to be downloaded. Setting `UserAgent` is better and can return the correct size. Lastly, does this Mozilla `UserAgent` works for all Http sources? Because I need it to be generalized. Thanks @Quentin.

Comment: Yes this user agent will works with all http sources. (If the url can be reachable with a standard browser)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sir! Fine answer

Comment: still same , wrong answer, does not creat difference.